# Cross domain session sharing does not work until site visited in browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, kohana-3

I have a script setup that allows me to communicate across two domains via JavaScript - from `foo.example.com` to `bar.example.com`.

When the cross-domain request hits my server I make sure to set the `Access Control Headers` as follows (in Kohana):

```
$this->response->headers('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'foo.example.com'));
$this->response->headers('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
$this->response->headers('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
```

I also make sure that Kohana knows I want to share my cookies across sub-domains:

```
Cookie::$expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
Cookie::$salt = 'salt-string-which-is-the-same-on-both-domains';
Cookie::$httponly = TRUE;
Cookie::$domain = '.example.com';
```

I've set JavaScript to use a single domain (as I have iframes going cross-domain as well):

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

I also use the `xhrFields` property when making my `$.ajax()` requests:

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem I have is that when I used this altogether to perform a cross-domain AJAX request the session on the second instance `bar.example.com` doesn't read from the cookie(s) sent to it. So if I dump the session it's just a blank session shell.

However if I hit the second instance directly and then try my AJAX scripts everything works as expected. Which leads me to believe the issue is with reading the cookie(s).

Any ideas?

Comment: if you need to use `ajax()` in the cross-browser environment you can use `jsonp` for data format

Comment: In this scenario I do not believe that will fix the issue. It works fine with JSON once I have visited the website. I think the issue is more to do with the session not picking up the existing domain shared cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found what is causing this issue. Because both domains are served by separate instance they have unique PHP environments running. My code is currently using the native PHP session - so when the cookie is sent to the second server it gets the ID to which no data is allocated.

It's only by visiting the site manually that triggers the allocation of data as it automatically runs through the authentication and authorisation procedure. I am going to switch to using database session in Kohana. Both instances point to the same DB so this should resolve the issue.

I'll post back here to confirm.